# A Short Connect Wall

Tags: word, pattern, connect-wall

The 16 words below may be partitioned into 4 groups of 4 connected words.
Additionally, each of the four groups can be represented by a single group-word.
Finally, the four group-words are connected by a single four-letter word.

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BANANA | BRITISH | CHASE | CUT |
| FORCEPS | FRONTIER | HUNTER | KNIFE |
| MOON | MUGGER | NOSE | PLANE |
| ROCK | ROLL | TEARS | TIGER |

**Can you identify the four groups and the associated group-words?**
**What is the four letter word that links the group-words together?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This Connecting Wall can be resolved thus:

> **Group 1: BREAD**
>  [BANANA Bread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banana_bread), Bread KNIFE, Bread ROLL, [TIGER Bread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiger_bread)
>
>  **Group 2: CROCODILE**
>  [*Crocodile HUNTER*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Irwin), [MUGGER Crocodile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mugger_crocodile), [Crocodile ROCK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crocodile_Rock), [Crocodile TEARS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crocodile_tears)
>
>  **Group 3: PAPER**
>  [Paper CHASE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_Chase), Paper CUT, [*Paper MOON*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_Moon_(film)), Paper PLANE
>
>  **Group 4: BULLDOG**
>  [BRITISH Bulldog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulldog), [Bulldog FORCEPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulldog_forceps), [FRONTIER Bulldog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frontier_Bulldog), [Bulldog NOSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulldog_nose)

The overall connection between these 4 categories is:

> **CLIP** - [BREAD Clip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bread_clip), [CROCODILE Clip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crocodile_clip), PAPER Clip, [BULLDOG Clip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulldog_clip).

And this fits with the title since:

> 'Clip' is also a synonym for 'shorten'!

Comment: Correct as always, well done!

Comment: I do love a [tag:connect-wall] puzzle :) Just need to get me a team together for Only Connect one day... (that's the dream)